# Intent String extra is SpannbleString, but isn't really

Tags: android, string, android-intent, spannablestring

This is the broadcast receiver class that I am using:

```
public class AlarmReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {

private Context context;
private String name;
private String description;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context c, Intent intent) {
    name = intent.getStringExtra("name");
    description = intent.getStringExtra("description");
    context = c;
    Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
    vibrator.vibrate(1000);
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
        .setContentText(description)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notificationicon)
        .setLights(Color.rgb(78, 155, 222), 1000, 1000)
        .setAutoCancel(true)
        .setContentTitle(name);
    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    manager.notify(1, builder.build());
}
```

}

My problem is that when I try to assign the String extras from the intent to the variables of the type string, I get these two errors:

> 12-30 20:34:45.224 14614-14614/eli.me.jitteralarm W/Bundle: Key name expected String but value was a android.text.SpannableString.  The default value  was returned.
>   12-30 20:34:45.224 14614-14614/eli.me.jitteralarm W/Bundle: Attempt to cast generated internal exception:
>                                                               java.lang.ClassCastException: android.text.SpannableString cannot be cast to java.lang.String
>                                                                   at android.os.BaseBundle.getString(BaseBundle.java:923)
>                                                                   at android.content.Intent.getStringExtra(Intent.java:5349)
>                                                                   at eli.me.jitteralarm.AlarmReciever.onReceive(AlarmReciever.java:22)
>                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2725)
>                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1421)
>                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
>                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
>
> 12-30 20:34:45.224 14614-14614/eli.me.jitteralarm W/Bundle: Key
>   description expected String but value was a
>   android.text.SpannableString.  The default value  was returned.
>   12-30 20:34:45.224 14614-14614/eli.me.jitteralarm W/Bundle: Attempt to
>   cast generated internal exception:
>                                                               java.lang.ClassCastException: android.text.SpannableString cannot be
>   cast to java.lang.String
>                                                                   at android.os.BaseBundle.getString(BaseBundle.java:923)
>                                                                   at android.content.Intent.getStringExtra(Intent.java:5349)
>                                                                   at eli.me.jitteralarm.AlarmReciever.onReceive(AlarmReciever.java:23)
>                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2725)
>                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1421)
>                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
>                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

I know that the result of getStringExtra is a SpannableString, but the return value of the method is a string (both on the autocomplete in intellij and on the documentation).

I have browsed around on the internet and found that you could kindof convert it to a string by trying:

```
name = "" + spannableString;
```

But when I try this the error is still thrown.

Another solution I have tried is to use .toString() on the "spannable string." When I do this, the app terminates immediately and the error that is thrown says the method can't be used on a string object. It's strange.

NOTE: While debugging  my application, the notification that is being sent would not have a title or discription the way the code is posted above. When i tried the conversion method, both the title and the description were both "null". What is the reason for this? Both errors said that it returned null to the variable instead of the desired title and description.

Also, this is the code where I try to use the broadcast reciever. I don't think this is the issue, but just in case here it is.

```
public void startAlarm(View view) {
    EditText nameInput = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.nameInput);
    EditText descriptionInput = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.descriptionInput);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReciever.class);
    intent.putExtra("name", nameInput.getText());
    intent.putExtra("description", descriptionInput.getText());
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
            this.getApplicationContext(), 234324243, intent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), pendingIntent);
}
```

Comment: where is `spannableString` in your code?

Comment: It isn't. The method returns a string value, but the two errors point to the .getStringExtra lines.

Comment: intent.putExtra("name", "abc");
intent.putExtra("description", "123"); can you try to put data by 2 lines. then tell me the error still show or not

Comment: I fixed the issue, thanks!

Comment: how you fixed, I have a solution in my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put `String` value via `Intent` because `nameInput.getText()` will return [Editable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html#getText())

```
public void startAlarm(View view) {
   ...
   intent.putExtra("name", nameInput.getText().toString());
   intent.putExtra("description", descriptionInput.getText().toString());
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution that worked for me:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
String contains = new StringBuilder(extras.getCharSequence("contains")).toString();
```